# transalte the strings of the onboarding page of android application

Tags: java, android, walkthrough

my app has two languages. i translated all the strings of the string file but I have four small texts on the onboarding/walkthrough activity java as a string array. the question is how can I store them in the string file and call them from java activity?

```
public SliderAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;

}
public int[] slide_images = {
        R.drawable.a1,
        R.drawable.a2,
        R.drawable.a3,
        R.drawable.a4
};
public String[] slide_headers = {
        "txt1",
        "txt2",
        "txt3",
        "txt4"
};
public String[] slide_desc = {
        "body1",
        "body2,
        "body3",
        "body4"
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a string array ressource: [Doc on developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StringArray)

In your example:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="slide_headers">
        <item>txt1</item>
        <item>txt2</item>
        <item>txt3</item>
        <item>txt4</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

JAVA:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] slide_headers = res.getStringArray(R.array.slide_headers);
```

Do same things to `slide_desc`.

You can translate your array-string xml file with the same way you translate your string xml file.

Comment: it doesn't work. the compiler doesn't recognize getResource();

Comment: Try `context.getResource()` in `SliderAdapter`

Comment: again it doesn't work. i got this error:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: it seems strange, can you put all the code of your activity?